# Store the Image/Video in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Which is the better to store the Image/Video between `Base-64` **OR** `URL of Server Path(physical Path i mean)`in MySQL. And what could be `variable` and `size` to store the **Video** of size ~3MB

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay

Comment: An interesting question for you to read through-> https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/150669/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-store-large-files-10-mb-in-a-database

Comment: For anything over 100k, it's best to store the path only.

Answer (score 0):

Store your videos in your hosting.
And store the link of video in MQSQL as a text data type.

mysql Query:

```
create table videos(
id int not null auto increment, 
  v_name varchar(100),
v_url text
);
```